# Support for Carousel view in Android 2.2

Tags: android, carousel

Is Android 2.2 supports Carousel view? Because most of the examples I came across is for Android 3.0.

NOTE: There is some problem with my internet thats why I cant be install Android 2.2 and test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the CarouselView requires RenderScript, and RenderScript is 3.0+ only. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564517/renderscript-usage) by one of the developers of Android.